# How to convert Steam string "Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource" to image source

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am sending image Source to other page like

```
    string bbb = dtnhd.imgsource.ToString();
```

Other page I got this:

```
     "Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource"
```

How I can change to "Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource" to image source.
I am using

```
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imagepath1);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Comment: don't covert it to a string before passing it

Comment: I am selecting a image from list view and I used code.
  if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                    return;

                var dtnhd = e.SelectedItem as MessageText;
                string bbb = dtnhd.imgsource.ToString();

  var _Popupspec = new ViewImageDialog(bbb);
                await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(_Popupspec);

Comment: Actually List view having text and image, So I send sting format